# How to debug `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'`

Tags: vb.net

I don't know what the problem is, but I think its because of the `baseamount` column and `withholding tax` column which is of type Integer.

```
Dim duplicate = From row In dt.AsEnumerable()
                Let tcode = row.Field(Of String)("TaxCode")
                Group row By tcode Into duptcode = Group
                Where duptcode.Count() = 1
                Select duptcode
For Each duptcoderows In duplicate
    For Each row In duptcoderows
        outFile.WriteLine(row.Field(Of String)("Tin") & "," & row.Field(Of String)("TaxCode") & "," & row.Field(Of String)("PayeeName") & "," & row.Field(Of String)("BaseAmount") & "," & row.Field(Of String)("WithHoldingTax"))
    Next
Next
```

Comment: i knew it change the ofstring into ofdouble

Answer (score 0):

This exception is caused by an explicit conversion you do in row.Field(Of Type) - in your case row.Field(Of String)

On result of this query LINQ  one or some data columns is different Type  - in your case Double

If you know the column name witch is do the correct conversion on this column OTHERWISE get all data in Object format like this:

```
 Console.WriteLine(row.Item("Tin") & "," &
                   row.Item("TaxCode") & "," &
                   row.Item("PayeeName") & "," &
                   row.Item("BaseAmount") & "," &
                   row.Item("WithHoldingTax"))
```